# Asking how to block Microsofts Telemetry/ Data collection/ Privacy Invasion push for older domain clients?

Tags: discussion

Is this not allowed?

Is this a business question or not? I got negative for a genuine business question that involves privacy from MS and no responses -

https://serverfault.com/questions/718232/disable-telemetry-data-privacy-invading-windows-updates-or-temporarily-all

This is a huge issue given that MS is now putting spy ware into all older Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Oh dear you got a downvote the world is ending.

> Is this not allowed?

Yes it looks acceptable.

> Is this a business question or not?

It seems so.

> I got negative for a genuine business question that involves privacy from MS and no responses -

Only the person who gave you the DV can say why they did it but they're not required to do so. People can and do vote as they see fit. It seems likely that you have jumped to the wrong conclusion though.

Coming to meta for a single DV is a huge waste of everyone's time.

Comment: `Coming to meta for a single DV is a huge waste of everyone's time.` +1, I was all ready to formulate an opinion on why the question was being received poorly and if it was valid before reading this... I wasted time!

Comment: @lain - I'm still figuring out how SF works differently from SU or SO. Each SE site with their flavors. So, I asked as this seemed like a key & pertinent thing "right now" given how MS is shoving telemetry down everyones throats.

Comment: SF works in exactly the same was as all SE sites. That your SF question has no answer in > 24 hours indicates that noone knows and or cares right now.  Your mSF question read like you're being whiney about a DV.

Comment: @Reaces - I dont know protocol for coming to Meta. I dont intend to waste peoples time. I just cleaned up the question.. Why does it have 4 negatives now? I am just trying to improve / refine and do right with a valid issue that lots of people are facing thanks to Microsoft

Answer (score 7):

Your question, while valid, is poorly written and hard to understand.  The repeat of the title in the question, the random **bolding** "**quoting**", and `other formatting`, and the disjointed nature of the writing, are all things that weigh against you. I'm not surprised someone downvoted it, because it is definitely "unclear", which is one of the reasons given in the tooltip shown when you hover over the downvote button.

Comment: It is an SBS Server & Doman in a critical business environment.How about I clean it up? Will that help or should delete and repost fresh?

Comment: @AlexS: Never, ever repost the same question because the first variant collected downvotes.

Comment: @Sven - Just cleaned it up. Is it better? Pleas do let me know.

Comment: @AlexS Personally I think your question is vastly less useful by all the extra information about the user-tracking updates. You want to stop specific windows updates `full stop`. That's your question. It's a basic question that should be easily dealt with by installing `WSUS` and setting those updates on `NotApproved`. Everything else is just bloat that's detracting from the question and causing more votes than you'd normally see.

Comment: @AlexS, your question's a lot better now; I agree with Reaces that you've still got a lot of largely irrelevant information, and it's still hard to know what exactly you've tried, and thus what your exact question actually *is*.  I'd lose the "news", summarise what you've done (with inline references to source material), and go for a plain text (no bolding), prose, "bottom-line up front" question as the first paragraph of your question, so people know exactly what you're asking, and *then* go into the background details.

Comment: @womble - I just deleted all the things I had tried from that question - I am wondering if you can go review the history. Most of it was steps / activities pieced together from the SF links I posted. I know its part of those SF answers, just not sure how to combine them. If you look at each, and tell me how to apply those "things" at the "right place" I'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I just voted to close it.  Try being more specific.  Do you want to control updates? Do you want to control telemetry?  What do news articles have to do with it?  Whichever problem you choose to tackle first, search for that answer and if you either can't find it or it doesn't work, you can then ask that question.

Comment: It is to contol updates specific to telemetry

Comment: Your question needs to actually say that and show what you've done to try

Comment: Jim - I have revised the question many times and feel it does say that. If you feel it does not say it and can be rephrased better please help me do so. Feel free to edit and improve it. What I've tried is also there.

Comment: Managing WSUS has been asked and answered, I'll mark it as a dup after revising

Comment: Jim - This not just any management of WSUS - Generic blocking of updates. This is specific to blocking the Telemetry updates, so little more needs to be added to the answer. PS: Also I havent installed WSUS on it. It is an SBS server

Comment: Blocking updates is blocking updates, whether its the ceip updates or any other update.  There are articles that you listed on how to handle it.

Comment: Either with or without Wsus you posted your own links to the solutions, so its still a dup.

Comment: I did not post links to a solution. I linked to things I combined and tried without success as SBS is slightly different {earlier I had even written all the steps in my question}, that are similar in nature - referring to them, but they are not the solution. 
PS: Honestly, do what you want, I am kind of feeling SE is not the place for me. No matter what/ how clearly something is articulated someone will come and be high & mighty. Thanks for the help so far. I give up.

Comment: Sbs has a wrapper around wsus and I put the link to that in the comment.